# Password popup not closing program if cancel is pressed

Tags: java

I am trying to make a password protected program. I can't seem to get my program to close if the person hits cancel. I also have another question. If my program is a jar file would `System.exit(0);` close it?

```
String password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(gameWindow,"Please enter the password.","Security Alert",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
if (password.equalsIgnoreCase("password")) {
} else {
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: you get NPE? I would assume so since it would cause an empty input

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know what NPE is. I did declare password as a String though.

Comment: NPE is null pointer exception. Try printing out the value of the password using System.out.println and see what the value is before you enter the if statement.

Comment: Ok. It printed null.

Comment: Nope. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting Null Pointer Exception.

Do the following for your if statement.

```
if (password != null && password.equalsIgnoreCase("password")) {
} else {
    System.exit(0);
}
```

When you do cancel password is set to null (same if you just exit), so you need to check for that, because otherwise your program crashes.

Comment: Ahh. Smart. I didn't think of testing if password != null.

Comment: But if this was a .jar would System.exit(0); still work?

Comment: It doesn't seem like it would because usually System.* refers to your command prompt or terminal. Right?

Comment: np, I didn't know you were doing a jar. If the jar is executable then yes it will exit. If the jar is a library then you should be returning value showing state.

Comment: Ok, it is an executable. I don't think I will be doing a library jar for a while.